# Get all keys of an NSDictionary as an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

Is it possible to get all the keys from a specific `NSDictionary` as a seperate `NSArray`?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

Just use

```
NSArray*keys=[dict allKeys];
```

In general, if you wonder if a specific class has a specific method, **look up Apple's own documentation**. In this case, see [NSDictionary class reference.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Go through all the methods. You'll discover many useful methods that way.

Comment: To get the first key only is NSString *firstKey = [dict allKeys][0];

Comment: @MazenKasser `firstObject` is a safer solution - in case if the dictionary doesn't have any keys the app won't crash: `dict.allKeys.firstObject;`

Comment: the order of keys returned by allKeys is undefined... so allKeys.firstObject or allKeys][0] is dangerous either way

Answer (score 17):

Yes it's possible. Use [allKeys](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method:

```
NSDictionary *yourDictionary;
NSArray * yourKeys
yourKeys = [yourDictionary allKeys];
```

Answer (score 3):

And if you want to get all keys **and values**, here's what you do:

```
for (NSString *key in dictionary) {
    id value = dictionary[key];
    NSLog(@"Value: %@ for key: %@", value, key);
}
```