# Getting Dictionary Keys for the Filtered Values

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having NSMutableDictionary (subjectValue) which contains value and keys. I want to filter based on the values searched for in search bar. So, I used the code like below.

```
NSArray *allvalues = [subjectValue allValues];
NSArray *filteredValues = [allvalues filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Now, filteredValues will have the values that are based on the search word.

Now, I want to get the Keys also for the filtered values got from the above result. I know how to get all values and all, but i want to get the keys for the filtered result.

Please advise how can i get that?

THIS IS NOT DUPLICATE OF THIS QUESTION. 
[Existing Query Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556905/filtering-nsdictionary-with-predicate)

What has been asked in the above link is, how to retrieve all values based on the predicate search. What I'm asking is beyond that. I already have got all filtered values, I want to get keys for that filtered values. My question is different.

Comment: This is NOT duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556905/filtering-nsdictionary-with-predicate

Comment: What they are asking is, how to retrieve all values based on the predicate search. What I'm asking is beyond that. I already have got all filtered values, I want to get keys for that filtered values. This question is different from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556905/filtering-nsdictionary-with-predicate

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057063/get-all-keys-of-an-nsdictionary-as-an-nsarray

Comment: I know getting all Keys. Please check my question, I need to get Keys for some values only.

Comment: You could use `- keysOfEntriesPassingTest:` to get an `NSSet` of the keys (based on a predicate that would be evaluated against values) and then `- objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:` to get an `NSArray` of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function keysOfEntriesPassingTest in [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/keysOfEntriesPassingTest:). Is that what you are looking for? Example:

```
NSDictionary *subjectValue = @{@"1":@"A", @"2":@"B", @"3":@"C", @"4":@"D"};
NSArray *filteredValues = @[@"B", @"D"];


NSSet *keys = [subjectValue keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^BOOL(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    return [filteredValues containsObject:obj];
}];
NSLog(@"%@", keys.description);
```

The output I get for that is {(4,2)} (NSSet)

Comment: No. I think, My question couldn't be understood. I have "VALUES" already. I.e, "NSMutableDictionary setObject: subjectValue Key:keys". In this, it contains all values "NSArray *allvalues = [subjectValue allValues];" Then, I am filtering to get some specific values based on the search word. This has put in "filteredValues" array. Now, I want to get the "KEYS" for which the "values (filteredValues)" have got.

Comment: In your sample, you have KEYS -> [@"B", @"D"] ? You are getting VALUE from this? Correct?

Comment: Also, [valuesToLookFor obj] line gives error as no visible interface for NSArray declares the selector obj

Comment: In my sample, the keys are the numbers i.e. 1, 2, 3 and 4 are the keys (sorry for this, the thing above is a quick way to create a dictionary but may not be so clear. The format is @{key1:value1, key2:value2...}

I fixed my code above

Comment: I modified the example to use what I think is your variable names

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you can get the keys for given values by a predicate-like method.
So if you have to enumerate the dictionary anyway, use something like this

```
 __block NSMutableDictionary * filteredDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  [subjectValue enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj matchesTheConditionOfThePredicate]) {
      filteredDictionary[key] = obj;
    }
  }];
```